# Nginx-ingress helm deployment - default backend only works with port 8080

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to set up an ingress for my kubernetes cluster using the ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx helm3 deployment. I took the default values.yaml file from the repo and made the following single change:

defaultBackend.enabled: true

I deployed this modified chart, and it worked fine. Next, I changed defaultBackend.port from 8080 to 80. I need to make this change because an application that I will be using in the tech stack looks for the default backend on port 80.

However, after changing the value of the port the default backend is not passing the health check probe anymore, so the pod doesn't spin up ever - It is just in an eternal crash loop:

Events:
Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message

---

Normal   Scheduled  3m18s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-defaultbackend-7bb7c8ff6c-kmwj6 to node1
Warning  Unhealthy  2m27s (x3 over 2m47s)  kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.233.64.173:80/healthz": dial tcp 10.233.64.173:80: connect: connection refused
Normal   Killing    2m27s                  kubelet            Container ingress-nginx-default-backend failed liveness probe, will be restarted

Note: Firewall is off (this is a poc), so that's not interfering with anything. Plus other health checks in the cluster were working fine before I adjusted the port. I'm pretty new to kubernetes administration still, so I'm suspecting that there are some nuances that I am missing for managing ingress resources.

If anyone could have a look, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Supplementary Info:
OS:
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009

Kubernetes:
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:28:09Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Docker:
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           19.03.15
API version:       1.40
Go version:        go1.13.15
Git commit:        99e3ed8919
Built:             Sat Jan 30 03:17:57 2021
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64

Comment: What do you mean by `an application that I will be using in the tech stack looks for the default backend on port 80.`?
Why your application can't connect to the `ingress-nginx-defaultbackend` `Service` associated with the default backend.
The `ingress-nginx-defaultbackend` `Service` listens on port 80 by default.

Comment: Hi @matt_j thanks for your response. It made a lot of sense to me. I re-deployed my stack ... with no changes .. and this time it worked.

I have no explanation for this. I probably missed something simple, but I just re-deployed with a chart I had previously used and it miraculosly worked.

Sometimes I feel like my tech stack just likes to gaslight me since im still learning this technology, haha!

Comment: that's great :) 
Are you using `ingress-nginx-defaultbackend` `Service` to communicate with the default backend ?